# Replacing special characters in scala

Tags: scala, replaceall

I am working on a scala and want to replace special characters from my dataframe `replaceAll` doesn't seem to work, is there any other way ?

My code is this:

```
val specialchar = dataframe.select(column).replaceAll("[^A-za-z]+","")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide specifics, please? A sample string and code that you tried.

Comment: I am trying to do it over a column ```val specialchar = dataframe.select(column).replaceAll("[^A-za-z]+","")```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the allowed characters in regex .

Try following

```
 val badDF = Seq(("7369", "SMI_)(TH" , "2010-12-17", "800.00"), ("7499", "AL@;__#$LEN","2011-02-20", "1600.00")).toDF("empno", "ename","hire_date", "sal")
 val cleanedDF = badDF.select(badDF.columns.map(c => regexp_replace(badDF(c), """[^A-Z a-z 0-9]""", "").alias(c)): _*)
 cleanedDF.show
```

**ename** contains special characters. above regex will only allow Capital/Small `a-z characters` and `0-9 digits`. All other characters will be removed.

[image]